# How does one delete a row from filtered data

Tags: excel, office365, office-js, excel-addins

I have set a filter on my table using the following code:

```
  let filter = taxTable.columns.getItem('Tax').filter;
  filter.apply({
      filterOn: Excel.FilterOn.values,
      values: ['.0']
  });

  let filterData = taxTable.getDataBodyRange();
  let visibleRange = filterData.getVisibleView().load('rowCount, rows');

  await context.sync();

  if (visibleRange.rowCount > 0) {
    // Delete individual rows ?????
  }
```

`visibleRange` is of type `Excel.RangeView` which does not have a `row.delete()` method.

So my question is how do you remove the filtered rows from the table?

Answer (score 0):

To delete rows, you have to work with the Range object's `row.delete()`, which in your case is the `flterData` object.